# Create Siri shortcut Swift pragmatically that open Apple Maps or google maps

Tags: swift, siri, sirishortcuts

Is it possible programmatically in swift to create Siri shortcut to open Apple Maps or google maps ?

It should be create shortcut that open google maps directly.

this shortcut I crate manually in shortcut app :

[image]

for now I create shortcut like this:

```
 let button = INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton(style: .whiteOutline)
        let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "comgooglemaps")
        activity.title = "MyAppTitle"
        activity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "MyApp"
        let iNShortcut = INShortcut(userActivity: activity)
        button.shortcut = iNShortcut
        button.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
```

In AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if userActivity.activityType == "comgooglemaps" {
        if let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://") ,UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

but it open my app and then open google maps